# Finding gaps between two lines

Tags: python, numpy, similarity

I have two lines. I determined the significant points where they diverge and converge as well as the points that are common among the traces.

To get the segments where the lines are different I use the following code snippet:

```
range = np.zeros(streamline.shape[0] ).astype("bool")
range[points_common] = True
range = ~range
i = np.arange(0, streamline.shape[0] )
different = i[range]
indices = np.where(np.diff(different) > 1)[0] + 1
different = np.split(different, indices)
```

where the variables look as follows:

```
range = array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])

points_common = array([ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,
        23,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,
        37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,
        50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,
        63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,
        76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,
        89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100])

different = [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([24])]
```

it works but I also want to include the first point where the traces diverge or converge (See the picture). Hence, the red linde should go to the black star and should also fill the gap between the cyan colored and second black star. [image]

Comment: Unrelated but you should not use `range` as a variable name since it is a python keyword.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have named it rang previously but for the sake of this post I have changed it to range to make clear it’s meaning :)